# User activation success page localization problem

Tags: users, activation

I have a website with Craft CMS 2 and this site has 2 diffrent languages.

There is no problem with sending e-mail for account activation for each language but when a user tries to activate his/her account via e-mail for my second language which is English they see English mail template but link directs them to my first and default language which is Turkish.

Same problem with the "Forgot my password" link. I tried to add array to `activateAccountSuccessPath` for each local like `siteUrl` but could not take any solution. Always directs to `tr` locale after activation from English mail template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register/save the user you need to set their `preferredLocale`, so Craft adjusts the verification URL sent with the activation email accordingly. Craft uses the primary locale for a user who doesn’t have a preferred locale set.

You can do this using a hidden input field in the registration form, or via a `users.beforeSaveUser` event listener.

```
<input type="hidden" name="preferredLocale" value="{{ craft.locale }}">
```

Once your users have a preferred locale set, your localized `activateAccountSuccessPath` config should work.

Comment: thanks for helping to solve my issue! Your code works fine and do what i need.